# How would you phrase something like "It sounds like you had a great time"?

Tags: english-to-german, sentence-structure

I'm working on a translation and I'm not sure about the right way to phrase "It sounds like you had a great time." The speaker is reporting to a second person about what the second person did, as understood from a third party. Would that be something like "Es klingt als ob du eine tolle/schöne Zeit gehabt hast"? Or maybe "Es hört sich für mich wie du eine tolle Zeit gehabt hast an" - but that seems like a ridiculous mouthful. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Es klingt, als ob du eine tolle Zeit gehabt hast" is a perfect translation.

Answer (score 5):

Don't translate the phrase *to have a great time* into German. It's one of 
those marker phrases which identify you as an English speaker.

Better refer to the emotion or the occasion talked about. In this case, *Spaß* or *Ausflug* or similar.

> Klingt, als hätte es viel Spaß gemacht.

*Sounds as it was a lot of fun.*

> Klingt nach einem sehr schönen Ausflug.

*Sounds like a very nice trip.*

Comment: Great answer.  Way to look out for the foreigner. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Du klingst [ja richtig] begeistert! / Du bist ja richtig begeistert!
>   *(Sounds enthusiastic!)*

should also be an option.